# Xamarin.Forms: Update UI when single property of elemt inside ObservableCollection changes

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an obserable collection of this type:

```cs
public class CategoryType
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public int tblCategoryID { get; set; }
   public string backgroundColor { get; set; } = "#2C2E31";
}
```

I have attached an gesture recognzier to it:

```cs
void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as Xamarin.Forms.Frame;
    var model = item.BindingContext as CategoryType;

    if (model.isSelected)
    {
        model.backgroundColor = "#2C2E31";
        model.isSelected = false;
    }
    else
    {
        model.isSelected = true;                 
        model.backgroundColor = "#60CED3";
    }
}
```

Upon click, the background color shall be changed. But the changes only take effect when the item is scrolled out of view and then scrolled back or when the view is loaded again.

I tried:

```cs
catList.CollectionChanged += CatList_CollectionChanged;
```

But this method is only called when the objects are assigned to the observablecollection not when a property is changed.

How can I achieve my affect and update the ui upon the click?

Comment: `CategoryType` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: INPC has been documented **thousands** of times on SO and elsewhere on the web.  For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From document [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm), we know that:

> ViewModels generally implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
> which means that the class fires a PropertyChanged event whenever one
> of its properties changes. The data binding mechanism in Xamarin.Forms
> attaches a handler to this PropertyChanged event so it can be notified
> when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new
> value.

You can refer to the following code:

```
    public class CategoryType:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //public string backgroundColor { get; set; } = "#2C2E31";

        private string _backgroundColor;
        public string backgroundColor
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _backgroundColor, value); }
            get { return _backgroundColor; }
        }

        public CategoryType(){
            backgroundColor = "#2C2E31";

        }   

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Ok sounds great, but how do I from this notify the observarable collectiton that it now is supposed to update the ui? Just the missing link for me...

Comment: If we want something like ListView to automatically update as items are added, removed and changed in the underlying list, we need to use an `ObservableCollection`. In addition, if  we implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for our model,once we modify the value of the property in our model , the UI will update automatically.

Comment: fantastic. thank you so much. works just as i hoped for. youre the BEST :)