# Can't update label after closing popup page xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, popup

I have datagridview in my popup page, select items from there then i want to update selected value on that main page. But i cant update that label. I bind this 2 pages the same viewmodel.
I control popup page close with this:

```
 protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        viewModel.CarilisteClose = true;
        
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
```

This is my property:

```
public bool CarilisteClose { get => carilisteClose; set {
            carilisteClose = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Console.WriteLine(carilisteClose);
            changeCariText(carilisteClose);
        } }
```

After that i can see from output that property True and selected item. But SearchCari cant update after pupoppage closing.

```
 public string SearchCari => $"{secilenCari}";
 void changeCariText (bool mbool ) {
        Console.WriteLine("change cari work");
        if (mbool==true)
        {
            
            var adi = Preferences.Get("selectedCariAdi", "");
            var kodu = Preferences.Get("selectedCariKodu", "");
            secilenCari = $"{kodu} {adi}";
            Console.WriteLine("cari liste close " + secilenCari);
            
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchCari));
            Console.WriteLine(SearchCari);
        }

        
    }


<Label Text="{Binding SearchCari}" x:Name="secilenCariText3" TextColor="Black"  FontSize="Medium" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="50"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

Edit:
Well, i realized that : I can not update label while closing the popup page but when i add button and set buttons command this changeCariText() it updates label.

**Update**
https://www.paste.tc/depoaktarimpageviewmodel
Viewmodel

https://www.paste.tc/depoaktarimpagexaml Xaml
https://www.paste.tc/caripopuppage 2nd page

**Solution :**
To save something :

CariRoot : Object to send

selectedCari : Selected object to send from this page.

mselectedCari : Key to seperate messages.

```
 MessagingCenter.Send<CariRoot>(selectedCari, "mselectedCari");
```

To get something you saved :

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CariRoot>(this, "mselectedCari" ,async (sender) =>
            {
              
                SearchCari = $"{sender.CARIUNVAN}";
                _SelectedCariRoot = sender;
             
               
            });
```

You need to use that code inside viewmodel.

Comment: *"I bind this 2 pages the same viewmodel."*: Depends how you did that. Did you create one instance `var myvm = new MyViewModel();`, then pass `myvm` as a parameter to both pages? If not, then you have two different instances, not a shared one. Add to question all mentions of your view model, in xaml and c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bind this 2 pages the same viewmodel.

Even if two pages use the same View Model, when two different pages are instantiated, two instances of the same class are created. Therefore, the two pages do not share the same value, even the same property.

But you can pass the data to the Viewmodel instance of the page that you want to update value for the special property.

There are several ways to pass data.

For example, you can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) or `EventHandler` to achieve this.

For how to use EventHandler, you can check thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74567945/10308336).

**Update:**

> I add a button to do that then changeCariText() function works fine
> update my text but when i close pouppage this changeCariText() doesn't
> update text.

Please recheck if you have implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your viewmodel and called `OnPropertyChanged` for the property you want to update the value and UI of it.

You can refer to the following code:

```
 public class YourViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
     
        private string _searchCari ;
        public string SearchCari 
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _searchCari, value); }
            get { return _searchCari; }
        }

  void changeCariText (bool mbool ) {
    Console.WriteLine("change cari work");
    if (mbool==true)
    {
        
        var adi = Preferences.Get("selectedCariAdi", "");
        var kodu = Preferences.Get("selectedCariKodu", "");
        secilenCari = $"{kodu} {adi}";
        Console.WriteLine("cari liste close " + secilenCari);
        
         // remove the following code 
        //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchCari));

       //assign value for SearchCari, the UI will update automatically.
       SearchCari = yourvalue；
        Console.WriteLine(SearchCari);
    }

    
  }

       // For brevity, omit the other code

        public YourViewModel(){
           // other code

        }   

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

### Update 2

You should still not figure out what the difference between two instances of a class is. Your two pages create two instances of the class `DepoAktarımPageViewModel`. You add a Button to page `DepoAktarımPage` to change the value of `SearchCari`, and you do it on the instance of page `DepoAktarımPage`. When you close page `CariPopUpPage`, you change the value of `SearchCari` on the instance of page `CariPopUpPage`. The two instances are unrelated, meaning that the data of the two instances is not shared, even if they are instances of the same class. So changing the value on the ViewModel of  page `CariPopUpPage` does not affect the data on the ViewModel of page `DepoAktarımPage` at all.

For this problem you can use `MessagingCenter` or `EventHandler` to achieve this.

For more information, you can check my first answer.

Comment: Im using Preferences to save that data and it works fine i guess but OnPropertyChanged() method doesn't work. I add a button to do that then changeCariText() function works fine update my text but when i close pouppage this changeCariText() doesn't update text. Do you have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: Have you implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged ` for your Viewmodel and called method `OnPropertyChanged` for the property you want to update the value and UI of it? For more information, you can check thead : [Update UI when single property of elemt inside ObservableCollection changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316226/xamarin-forms-update-ui-when-single-property-of-elemt-inside-observablecollecti/69331068#69331068).

Comment: You can check the updated part of my answer.

Comment: public class DepoAktarımPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
Implemented already. Interesting thing i can update with a button same code but when i close Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage this code doesnt work. It does not update SearchCari text. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried this `private string _searchCari ;
        public string SearchCari 
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _searchCari, value); }
            get { return _searchCari; }
        }`   ?

Comment: I saw you edited first message then i do necessary changes but this also doesnt work. changeCariText() works but cant not effect UI.  But button changes UI. Nothing changes. Is there any other way to update UI ?

Comment: Could you please post the full code of your ViewModel?

Comment: I updated first message.

Comment: I'm tryng Messaging Center now, if i will stuck somewhere i will ask you. By the way thank you a lot, you are very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Waiting for your good news. :)

Comment: Finally! Good news! I could this messaging center work. Now my SearchCari string updates after selecting.

Comment: I gave you up already but i have 11 rep point; when i give rep point cant apply now, it will apply when its 15. :) Thank you very much again. :)

Comment: You are welcome, and I have posted a new answer for your new problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628893/page-title-not-shown-on-content-page).  And I found that you have got more than 15 reputations.  :)

Comment: You help me a lot, I give your points now. :)