# Page Title Not Shown On Content Page

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I set visibiliy of this page's navigation bar and my title was gone like that.
But there is a bluebar i can navigate back. I'm new at xamarin forms. I dont know its name but it works now. I want to show my page's title on that blue bar, not the Navigation bar. My page title must be shown on that empty space on the picture. How can i do that ?

[image]
Xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:İdaServis.ViewModels"
        xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:İdaServis.CustomRenderer"
        x:Class="İdaServis.View.PageName"
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        x:Name="Page"
        BackgroundColor="White">
 </ContentPage>
```

CS:

```cs
public PageName()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

Comment: it sounds like you might have two nested navigation pages

Comment: Firstly i was using flyoutpage but i cant fix some problems. Then i quit out of flyout but my mainpage remain flyoutmainmenu still. Now it looks like i'm opening a normal page inside flytoutpage. It works fine now but i had to change its title and show it.

Comment: Are you saying that you have solved your problem? If so, please add "Your Answer" below, showing the code that works.

Comment: No its not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your problem, I added a `LoginPage` to offcial sample [FlyoutSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-flyoutpage/).

The class order is: `App.cs` --> `Login`--> `MainPage(FlyoutPage)`.

The steps are as follows:

1.In `App.cs`,replace `MainPage = new FlyoutPageNavigation.MainPage ();` with `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());`

```
  public class App : Application 
      {
            public App ()
            {
                  //MainPage = new FlyoutPageNavigation.MainPage ();
                  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());

            }

  }
```

2.On Page `Login.xaml.cs`,add a Button to navigate to `MainPage(FlyoutPage)`

```
      public partial class Login : ContentPage 
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());// this will add another navigate bar

        // Navigation.PushModalAsync will not add the navigate bar
        //Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

**Note:**

In method `Button_Clicked`,if you used the following code, a navigate bar will be added to the top of the screen.  If you used `FlyoutPage`,there is no need to add this navigate bar.

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

So, try to use `Navigation.PushModalAsync` instead:

```
  Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
```

Comment: Well, Thank you very much Jessie! This PushModalAsync method really works well but i wonder about that when i go to other page what happens that page i was coming from ? Imagine 3 pages and i went with PushModalAsync method that third page and what would happen that two pages ? I'm asking that i dont want to use too many memory in this application.

Comment: You can pop pages from the modal stack. For more information,check document:   [Popping Pages from the Modal Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal#popping-pages-from-the-modal-stack).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show my page's title on that blue bar, not the Navigation
> bar.

If you want show your page's title on that blue bar, please set the second parameter of `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar` to `true` :

```
 public PageName()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
}
```

Then you can set your page's title by adding code  `Title="My Page"` for your Page. Just as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="My Page"
             x:Class="MVVMApp.SecondPage">

   
</ContentPage>
```

Of cource, you can also custom this with `TitleView`.

For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="My Page"
             x:Class="MVVMApp.SecondPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label  Text="custom TitleView----->"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to secoend page"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This makes doubles that blue bar, i guess its cuz of flyout. you can see here : https://imgur.com/2tEHR81

Comment: These pages are flyoutitempage https://www.paste.tc/flyoutitempage you can see here. But I guess it goes off flyout when I click on it. Then it makes doubles navigation bar 1 comes from flyout 1 comes from this custom item page I guess.  I'm not sure that. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please check my new answer. :)